# JavaScript/jQuery Define onchange in Object-Oriented Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop, onchange

I have a class that I have defined, and I would like all of its objects to do the same thing on change.  Here is a simplified example:

```
var firstName = new Field('#firstName');

function Field (tag) {

    this.section = $(tag);

    this.section.on('change', function(){
        alert("You've changed it!");
    });

}
```

jQuery has been invoked before the start of this script.

Please let me know your suggestions so that whenever someone changes #firstName, it will do whatever I put in the closure function.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems like a hard way to attach a simple event handler, but it should work fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/ufvhrhpc/

Comment: is there any issue you are facing? what you want to accomplish

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback.  I realized why it wasn't working the way I did it.

I have many other methods and properties in the class besides the change function.  I wanted the change function to validate the field on change, but it wasn't working.  It turns out it wasn't working because I was instantiating each object within the $('#form').submit(function(){}); closure instead of outside of it, so it wouldn't validate on change until after the user submitted the form, which defeated the purpose, but I understand now that I need to instantiate it outside of the submit closure.